# SUMIF in a SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I wrote a query which aggregates some values from a table but I would like to add another column to this query which does another aggregation, just like `SUMIF` in Excel.

So, as in the below example, I would like to add column `SUMMV` which would work the same as `=SUMIF(A:A,A1,B:B)`.

Please keep in mind that in my query column `MV` is an aggregation of some other column.

| NAME | MV | SumMV |
| --- | --- | --- |
| X | 2 | 5 |
| Y | 1 | 6 |
| Z | 3 | 4 |
| X | 3 | 5 |
| Z | 1 | 4 |
| Y | 5 | 6 |

My query looks like below:

Select E.Name, P.ID, P.Key, P.Name,P.type, P.MV, , P.Exp as TNA,
FROM tblposition P INNER JOIN  QScope ON E P.ID=E.ID
WHERE Type NOT IN (2,5,10,15)

UNION ALL
Select E.Name, P.ID, P.Key, P.Name,P.Type, sum(P.MV) AS MV, , P.Exp as TNA,
FROM tblposition P INNER JOIN  QScope ON E P.ID=E.ID
WHERE Type IN (2,5,10,15)
AND P.MVT > -0.01
GROUP BY P.Key,P.ID,P.Name,P.Type,P.Exp
ORDER BY Name, Type

Comment: You've tagged three very different RDBMS's (mysql, sql server and ms access). What are you wanting is generally solved with window functions, but those won't work in older versions of mysql and any version of MSAccess. Can you clarify which RDBMS you are using and delete the wrong tags?

Comment: it cannot be both mysql, and sql-server at the same time. Please fix the tags. Also, are you trying to get help in ms-access?
Set your tags to reflect what you want help with.

Comment: With the latest update, the tags make even less sense...

Comment: Please also share your existing SQL as combining window functions with GROUP BY can be a little different for each product. Solution will likely look like `SUM(Value) OVER (PARTITION BY ID) as SumValue` but ymmv.

Comment: How did you get query to return multiple rows for each ID?

Comment: Access SQL does have a PARTITION function but not OVER keyword. The Access PARTITION won't do what you want. https://sfmagazine.com/post-entry/february-2019-access-age-overdue-accounts-with-partition/

Comment: Posted SQL has errors that make it invalid. Should provide sample raw data and desired output as well as attempt to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Options in Access:

1. Build a query that aggregates by ID then join that query to the first query
2. Calculate field with DSum() domain aggregate function - however, this can cause slow performance in queries
   `DSum("Value", "table or query name", "ID=" & [ID]) AS SumValue`
3. Build a VBA custom function and call it in the first query - this function would either open a recordset object or execute DSum()

Comment: I edited my initial post just to gave you a pricture of this query

Comment: Doesn't change my answer.

Answer (score 0):

There are no Windowing functions in AccessSQL but you can use a subquery either on the SELECT clause, or in the FROM part. Something like this:

```
Select 
     E.Name
   , P.MV
   , (select sum(P2.MV)
      FROM tblposition P2 
           
           INNER JOIN 
           QScope e2 ON P2.ID=E2.ID 
      WHERE P2.Type NOT IN (2,5,10,15)
      AND p1.Name=P.Name
     ) as SumMV
 
FROM tblposition P 

     INNER JOIN 
     QScope ON E P.ID=E.ID 
WHERE P.Type NOT IN (2,5,10,15)
```

should work, but I can't say it is correct because you haven't given us the table structures or sample data from each table.